# Does a users request be checked by performing queries in flutter with mongoDb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter

A phoneNunmber exist in mongoDb and am trying to signup with same number and expect a snackBar but when i tried it didnt and am not sure the problem is from the query.But it is any idea to the problem or suggestion will be welcome.Thank you
This is the User page

```
       
    // import 'package:modal_progress_hud_nsn/modal_progress_hud_nsn.dart';
    class Login extends StatefulWidget {
      static String login = '';
      @override
      _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
    }
    
    class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
    
      String number = '00000';
      String password = 'emonearth';
    
    
      mongoconnection() async {
        var db;
        try {
          db = Db("mongodb://10.0.2.2:8000/course");
          await db.open();
    
          var collectiondocument = await db.collection("usersinfos");
    
          var existingNumber = where.eq('phoneNumber', number);
    
          final checkNumber = await collectiondocument.findOne(existingNumber);
    
          await db.close();
          
           if (number == checkNumber) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(content: Text("PhoneNumber already exist ")));
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print(e.toString());
        }
      }
    
      Future registerUser() async {
        var sendUserDetails;
    
        var registerdetails = {"phoneNumber": number, "password": password};
    
        if (number != null && password != null) {
          sendUserDetails =  http.post(Uri.parse(register),
              headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
              body: jsonEncode(registerdetails));

        } else {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(content: Text("PhoneNumber and password are required")));
        }
    
        return sendUserDetails;
      }
    
      void UserData() {
        var UserAndConnection = [];
        UserAndConnection.add(registerUser());
        UserAndConnection.add(mongoconnection());
    
        switch (UserAndConnection.length) {
          case 1:
            UserAndConnection[1];
            break;
          case 2:
            UserAndConnection[0];
            break;
          default:
          
            break;
        }
      }
```

And this is my node js in case of any reference

```
    
    const Signup=asynchandler(async(req,res)=>{
        const {phoneNumber,password}=req.body;
    
        
        const findNumber=await Users.findOne({phoneNumber});
        
        if(findNumber){
            res.status(404);
            throw new Error("Number already exist");
        }
    
        const hashedpassword= await brypt.hash(password,10);
        
        const newusers=await Users.create({
            phoneNumber,password:hashedpassword,
        });
    
        res.status(200).json(newusers);
   
    
    });
    
    module.exports={Signup,LoginUser,getCurrentUser};
```

I also tried decoding the sendUserDetails to get the phoneNumber to compare it to the phoneNumber in the database but also did not show the snackBar

```
         
            var jsonbody = jsonDecode(sendUserDetails.body);
            if (jsonbody[0] == checkNumber) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(content: Text("PhoneNumber already exist ")));
            }
```

Comment: In order to get assistance you'll need to clarify the problem, what behavior you're observing versus what you're expecting, and probably narrow down your code to a smaller sample that demonstrates the problem

Comment: OK please i have made few alteration and clarified the details to the question